# Qt select specific kit

Tags: c++, qt

I have a qt project where I wish to use a specific custom kit. The problem is when I build the project it uses the auto-detected kit. I mention that i already made the custom kit default.

How can I build the project using just the custom kit? I can not disable that kit because it is auto-detected and I do not wish to remove it because I will need it for future projects. The auto-detected kit uses qt version 5.6 with 2013 visual studio and the custom one that I need uses 4.8 version with 2008 visual. For the project I use qt creator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the Project button on the left side of Creator (the wrench), there you will see an "add kit" button, for each existing kit you also have a drop down menu with a remove button and a change button.

[image]

There you can either add your custom kit to the project, or replace the default kit with yours.

You can quickly select which kit is active from the icon in the bottom:

[image]

Comment: I already checked this solution but it seems it is not available in express version of qt. I manage to make it work by deleting the generated pro file and run it again and then choose the version. In any case this is a valid solution.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "express version of qt".

Comment: I do not posses this features.